# How can i convert a react componet into a object , any online tool?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

react element

```
const element = (
  <h1 className="heading" tabIndex={index}>Hellow world</h1>
)
```

js object

```
element = {
  type: 'h1',
  props: {
    className: 'heading',
    tabIndex: 0,
    children: 'Hellow World'
  }
}
```

Comment: try this online tool. it is closed to the one u asked.. [https://infoheap.com/online-react-jsx-to-javascript/](https://infoheap.com/online-react-jsx-to-javascript/).

Comment: its close, but not enough what i want.